# Automatic usage of Upload bandwidth. How to prevent this?

Tags: windows, networking, bandwidth

My network usage is tremendously increasing from the last couple of days. My upload bandwidth increases everyday. After turning on the computer in the morning and within the next one hour, upload bandwidth reaches above 1 GB.

I am using Windows 8.1 Pro OS. Automatic update is turned off. Recommended updates are turned off.

But everyday upload bandwidth goes higher. No problem with the download bandwidth. It seems normal. I amusing NetWorx to monitor my bandwidth usage.

Comment: I think you need a different tool, one that will monitor application level network usage.

Comment: Then suggest me one. @Paul

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: It could be a result of the machine being infected with a virus, the virus then generates a lot of traffic trying to infect new machines or by being part of a botnet and spamming other hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you don't have running in background applications like bitTorrent, OneDrive, Dropbox, etc that could be doing uploading tasks automatically.

Also, use a malware scanner tool to find possible troyans and botnets that could be using your PC to do DDoS attacks.

In Command Prompt (cmd) you can use the command `netstat -a` to know the connections that you have opened and established.